# Access a nested element in php array

Tags: php, arrays, object, for-loop

I have a PHP object that print_r's with this result

```
 fieldData: {},
portalData: {
    SubCategories: {
        0: {},
        1: {
            recordId: "3",
            SubCategories::SubCategoryName: "Multi-Channel",
            modId: "0"
    },
        2: {},
        3: {}
    }
},
recordId: "2",
modId: "3"
```

How do I access the SubCategoryName?

Comment: Where does the structure and values come from? It feels like a better approach would be to create the object differently when you populate it.

Comment: thanks for fast reply im trying to access this:             SubCategories::SubCategoryName: "Multi-Channel",

Comment: I can access the other variables using:  SubCategories->recordId; for instance

Comment: You should be able to access it using: `$object->portalData->SubCategories->{1}->{'SubCategories::SubCategoryName'}`

Comment: Magnus I could kiss you thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access it using:

```
$object->portalData->SubCategories->{1}->{'SubCategories::SubCategoryName'}
```

– Magnus Eriksson 2 mins ago